# Help with loading contents on XNA (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, xna

I've used till last week VS 2008 so I'm not really used for VS 2010.
I've loaded earlier a content(add reference) and I don't see it in the side of the toolbar(I mean the right side where all the references are just like VS 2008, and when I try to load that texture I added I'm getting an error "File not found", maybe I'm doing something wrong with loading the content?
This is the code with the loading content:

```
player.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship_animated"), playerPosition);
```

Please, I really need help with this, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Content files (images, sounds, music, 3d models, etc) is not added "as a reference".

Adding a reference relates only to adding an Assembly reference to your project (code).

In order to add content, navigate to your *Content Project*, this is where all the actual content of your game is placed, right click on the project, and add items there.

A simpler way is to copy a file from Windows Explorer and paste it into the content project in visual studio.

What sort of project are you creating? For an XNA 4.0 game project, there will be a content project generated to go with it:

[image]

It is this project to which you should be adding the content items (images, etc).

What version of Visual Studio are you using ? I am using the Professional version.

Comment: When I'm trying to to paste the picture in to the content project, I don't have the paste option(the content project is in the right of the VS program right?)

Comment: when I do right click on the project content I only see the following options: "add reference, debug, and sort options"

Comment: @Richard: If you right mouse click your `Content` project, you can `Add an existing item`.  Use this option and locate your file.